# Hiding/Showing form inputs based on checkbox checked or not

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using jquery to show and/or hide form inputs based on whether or not a checkbox is checked.
My js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  jQuery ->
    $(".refrigerator_style").hide()
      $("#contract_refrigerator").on "change", ->
        $(".refrigerator_style").slideToggle()
        return
```

My form.html.haml

```
.form-group
  .col-sm-offset-3.col-sm-6
    .checkbox
      %label
        = f.check_box(:refrigerator, {}, "Yes", "No")
        %strong Refrigerator
.refrigerator_style
  .form-group
     %label.col-xs-6.col-sm-3.control-label Refrigerator Style
     .col-sm-6
      = f.collection_select :refrigerator_style, StandardOption.available.where(room:           "Refrigerator"), :name, :name, {:include_blank => " "}, { :class => 'form-control'}
```

How can I get the div's to show if the checkbox is checked, and/or stay hidden if the checkbox is not checked when editing?

Answer (score 0):

First off you should use `.toggle()` instead of `.slideToggle()`

You also don't need to hide it in the js.  You can initialize the checked attribute in the html.  Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5pb576qo/7/).

Good luck.

Comment: .toggle() and .slideToggle() essentially do the same thing, only difference is the slide animation.  Also, I'm not writing straight HTML...I'm using Rails 4.  The issue is only when the user goes in to edit something, default state is .hide() so even if a checkbox is checked, the hidden input is still hidden.  I need to make it to where if checkbox is checked...input is not hidden.